# Task :expo-modules-core$android-annotation:compileKotlin FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am trying to build my `React-Native` application on Android using `Expo`. For iOS building has no problem at all for once but Android has the following issue. The issue occurs when executing on of the following commands:

- `eas build --profile development --platform android`
- `npx expo run:android`

**Error**

```
The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build. 
This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.
If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':expo', ':expo-modules-core'

Task :expo-modules-core$android-annotation:compileKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core$android-annotation:compileKotlin'.
 Error while evaluating property 'compilerOptions.jvmTarget' of task ':expo-modules-core$android-annotation:compileKotlin'.
    Failed to calculate the value of property 'jvmTarget'.
       Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 20
```

I do not understand why this is happening and hope you can help me! I have tried the following items:

- `npx expo prebuild` ==> did not do anything
- `./gradlew clean` ==> Works fine

**Package.json**

```json
    {
      "name": "App",
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "main": "./index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start --dev-client",
        "android": "expo run:android",
        "ios": "expo run:ios",
        "web": "expo start --web"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@mdi/js": "^7.2.96",
        "@mdi/react": "^1.6.1",
        "@os-team/i18next-react-native-language-detector": "^1.0.28",
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "github:react-native-community/async-storage",
        "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
        "@react-native-cookies/cookies": "^6.2.1",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
        "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.17",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
        "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.14",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
        "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
        "axios": "^1.5.1",
        "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
        "expo": "~49.0.8",
        "expo-clipboard": "~4.3.1",
        "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.11",
        "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
        "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
        "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
        "expo-system-ui": "^2.6.0",
        "jotai": "^2.6.0",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.49.2",
        "react-i18next": "^13.2.2",
        "react-native": "0.72.4",
        "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
        "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
        "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
        "react-native-onesignal": "^4.5.0",
        "react-native-paper": "^5.10.6",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
        "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
        "react-native-svg": "^13.13.0",
        "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
        "styled-components": "^6.0.7",
        "swagger-ui": "^5.9.0",
        "swagger-ui-react": "^5.9.0",
        "swr": "^2.0.0",
        "yup": "^1.3.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
        "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.10",
        "@types/react-native": "^0.72.2",
        "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.2.5",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.14.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.14.0",
        "eslint": "^8.55.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^6.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^3.0.0",
        "husky": "^8.0.2",
        "react-native-flipper": "^0.176.1",
        "rn-mmkv-storage-flipper": "^1.0.0",
        "typescript": "^5.3.3"
      },
      "private": true
    }
```

I really hope you can help me with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occurred.
It seems to be caused by an older version of kotlin.

Fix the `android/build.gradle` file.

e.g.

- Remove `classpath('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10')`
- Fix kotlinVersion